# Equivalent to route guards for component functions

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I'm wondering if there is an equivalent to route guards for angular component functions (specifically click events).

We've got a route guard set up that opens a login page when not logged in. This works great. The problem is, we have a component that does not require authentication to view, but some of the functionality within the component does require authentication. For example, a list of news articles, but the upvote/downvote buttons require authentication to use.

The upvote/downvote buttons are simply click events firing component functions. We can take the logic we are using in our custom route guard, and add it to these functions, but this leads to quite a bit of duplicate code.

I was wondering if Angular has anything built in that can solve this. I'm thinking something similar to ASP.NET MVC's [Authorize] attribute that you can put at the top of an action to authenticate. As far as I can tell, route guards only work for routes, and not click events.

Comment: There’s nothing like guards for functions but I believe you have some kind of auth.service and you can check authService.isAuthorized() on click. Another way to protect here will be to hide those buttons from DOM completely using *ngIf again referencing to some Boolean in your component which you can set in ngOnInit. If you need to track isAuthorized dynamically you can put event emitter or subject in your authService that will propagate changes and subscribe to it.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone interested in a solution, I was able to figure out how to use my existing route guard within a function. This eliminated the need of an if/else statement where the else statement included the logic that the route guard was doing if unauthenticated. Seems to be the cleanest solution I could find.

```html
constructor(private authGuard: AuthGuard, private route: ActivatedRoute){}

upvoteClick(article: NewsArticle): void {

    if (this.authGuard.canActivate(this.route.snapshot)) {
        //logic requiring authentication
    } 
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to implement action guard. It is interceptor.
When action sends request to server without valid token or w/o necessary data, server returns 401 or 403, depends on your set up

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpAuthInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private toasterService: ToasterService,
    private auth: AuthService,
    private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  public intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.auth.token}`
      }
    });

    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(catchError(error => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          switch (error.status) {
            case 401:
              this.auth.logout(request.urlWithParams);
              this.dialog.closeAll();
              break;
            case 403:
              this.dialog.closeAll();

              this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
              
                autoFocus: false,
                width: '65rem',
                maxHeight: '95vh',
                maxWidth: '80vw',
                panelClass: 'confirme__dialog',
                data: {
                  title: 'CONFIRM_DIALOG.TITLE',
                  text: 'CONFIRM_DIALOG.TEXT',
                  onConfirm: () => {
                    this.auth.logout(request.urlWithParams)
                  }
                }
              });

              break;
            case 0:
              this.toasterService.error(error.message, {
                duration: 5000,
              });
              break;
            default:
              this.toasterService.error(error.error.Message, {
                duration: 5000,
              });
          }
        }

        return throwError(error);
      }));

  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How is your route guard testing if your user is logged in?  Hopefully, you have set up an authorization service which checks that and injected it into your guard.  If so, inject it into your vote component and simply use *ngIf to hide/show the vote buttons based on whether the user is logged in or not.

Comment: Yep I've got a service that I can inject to determine if a user is authenticated (same one I use in the route guard). I guess my issue is that I don't want to hide the buttons, I want them to still enter the click listener function, but prompt the login window if not authenticated. I can do all of this, but I was hoping there would be a way to avoid having the if/else statement in every function I want authenticated with the else containing the redirects to the login window. But if that's what I need to do, that's what I need to do!